# Switch statement not doing what I expect

Tags: c

What is wrong with this code:

```
switch (n)
{
    case 0:   strcpy(resultString, "Zero");
    case 1:   strcpy(resultString, "One");
    case 2:   strcpy(resultString, "Two");
    case 3:   strcpy(resultString, "Three");
    case 4:   strcpy(resultString, "Four");
    case 5:   strcpy(resultString, "Five");
    case 6:   strcpy(resultString, "Six");
    case 7:   strcpy(resultString, "Seven");
    case 8:   strcpy(resultString, "Eight");
    case 9:   strcpy(resultString, "Nine");
}
printf("%s", resultString);
```

It always prints "Nine" no matter the value of n.  What am I doing wrong??

Comment: A C `switch` statement is essentially a computed `goto`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a break statement at the end of each case.  Otherwise control falls straight through to the next case.

Change your code to:

```
switch (n)
{
    case 0: strcpy(resultString, "Zero"); 
            break;
    case 1: strcpy(resultString, "One"); 
            break;
    case 2: strcpy(resultString, "Two"); 
            break;
    case 3: strcpy(resultString, "Three"); 
            break;
    case 4: strcpy(resultString, "Four"); 
            break;
    case 5: strcpy(resultString, "Five"); 
            break;
    case 6: strcpy(resultString, "Six"); 
            break;
    case 7: strcpy(resultString, "Seven"); 
            break;
    case 8: strcpy(resultString, "Eight"); 
            break;
    case 9: strcpy(resultString, "Nine"); 
            break;
}
printf("%s", resultString);
```

You can find the switch statement documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a.aspx) or in any book on the C language.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to C in case you couldn't tell.

Answer (score 4):

You need to break after each case.

```
case 0: 

do soemthing;

 break;

case 1:

 do something;

 break;
```

In many managed languages, it won't let "one case fall through to another," and throws an error.  But C loves to let you do whatever you want!

Comment: Also put a default in, so if someone puts something >9 or <0

Answer (score 1):

You missed `break;` after each case

```
Example :
 case 0:   strcpy(resultString, "Zero");break;
 ..
 ..
 case 8: .... ; break;
 ..
```

Comment: Just telling him what to do won't help the OP in the future. You need to say _why_ break statements are necessary.

Comment: @JakeWilson Okay sir ! Fyi...if that is the case OP shouldn't have posted the question

Answer (score 1):

From the standard :

> **6.4.2 The switch statement [stmt.switch]**
>
> case and default labels in themselves do not alter the ﬂow of control, which continues unimpeded across such labels. **To exit from a `switch`, see `break` (6.6.1).**
>
> **6.6.1 The break statement [stmt.break]**
>
> The `break` statement shall occur only in an iteration-statement or a `switch` statement and causes termination of the smallest enclosing iteration-statement or switch statement; control passes to the statement following the terminated statement, if any.

That means that is you don't use `break` after each `case`, you program will enter in the first `case` who matches the condition and will continue executing every line of the `switch` until the end.

You should just do something like :

```
switch( n )
{
    case 0:
        // ...
        break; // <- Note the break
    //...

    default:
        // ...
}
```